# Why can't I run python scripts from the command line interactive session using "./ name.py"?

Tags: python-2.7, syntax

I'm following along with Google's Python class, and the person in the videos always runs his scripts from the interactive session in command line using "./". Whenever I try it, I just get a syntax error. How can I use ./ to run scripts? I'm using Windows 10

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Please show what exactly you type and where you type it.

Comment: what commands are you trying to run in what directory?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I am typing './hello.py' to run the script hello.py. When I type that into the interactive python shell in command line, it gives me [this](https://imgur.com/a/VvdicxS) To get to the shell, I'm just using cd to get to the folder that the script is in and type "python"

Comment: "Interactive Python session" and "command line" (a.k.a. shell) are two different things. The `./` syntax is used in the command line, not inside Python.

Comment: More specifically, it is used in unix-style shells. It won’t work in Windows. In the Windows command prompt you need to type `python name.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a script from the command line you need to use the syntax

```
python3 script.py
```

Now on Unix systems, it's possible to add a `shebang` to the first line of the script as followings

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

This then allows the shell syntax './name.py' to work. But windows doesn't have this mechanism. Instead, you need to create an 'association' between the .py extension and the python executable ('right click', 'open with'). Or just use the full syntax. Both require the python executable to be in your path, and generally on windows both python 2 and 3 will have the same executable name